# Errbit returns '422 Unprocessable Entity' using airbrake/javabrake

Tags: airbrake, http-status-code-422, errbit

Onboarding a Kotlin App to errbit 0.6.0 using airbrake/javabrake 0.1.6 client lib. Getting a '422 Unprocessable Entity' and HTML body.

I can see that client lib is using airbrake v3 API. Does errbit 0.6.0 support that?

Is there any mapping doc on what API versions are supported for each version of Errbit?

Comment: Errbit does intend support the airbrake notification API v3, although that has been a bit of a moving target. I'd recommend upgrading to Errbit v0.8 to make sure this bug hasn't already been solved, and if that doesn't work, then please try to post the contents of your request body (scrubbed of any secret things).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Stephen Crosby. Good to know that v3 is intended to be supported. Unfortunately I don't manage the server. I suppose I could try running up a local instance of v0.8 and seeing if that works. If it does, I could then see what the appetite is for upgrading the main server.